# Wrote a function to test each object in an array for specific key, continuously getting false even when the key is present

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a React component where I'm trying to conditionally render a checkbox only if any of the items in a data response contain an object key archived and it's truthy.

I've written a function to check each object but I keep getting false no matter what, even when I add an archived key for each object and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is my current function and a working [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-meadow-xlwuq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) sample:

```
    const hasArchived = (groupItems) => {
      let answer;

      for (let i = 0; i < groupItems.length; i++) {
        groupItems[i].hasOwnProperty("archived")
          ? (answer = true)
          : (answer = false);
      }

      return answer;
    };
```

And this is an example of the groupItems data set:

```
[
 [
   {
     name: 'item 1'
     groupName: 'Marvel Characters'
     archived: false
   },
   {
     name: 'item 2'
     groupName: 'Marvel Characters'
     archived: true
   },
   {
     name: 'item 3'
     groupName: 'Marvel Characters'
     archived: false
   }
 ],
 [
   {
     name: 'item 1'
     groupName: 'DC Characters'
     archived: false
   },
   {
     name: 'item 2'
     groupName: 'DC Characters'
     archived: true
   },
   {
     name: 'item 3'
     groupName: 'DC Characters'
     archived: false
   }
 ]
]
```

Comment: Is this an array inside an other array or just a typo ? Edit: nevermind, i'm tired

Comment: Your for loop keeps overwriting `answer`, effectively only checking the last item. You need to set answer to `false` as a default value, then set it to `true` inside the loop *if* the current has the `archived` property.

Comment: Btw, you'd use the reverse of that if you wanted to check whether *all* items have the property: assume it's true, then set `answer` to false inside the loop if a single item fails the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your array has two levels of depth, also you could use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for this use case:

```js
const data = [
 [
   {
     name: 'item 1',
     groupName: 'Marvel Characters',
     archived: false
   },
   {
     name: 'item 2',
     groupName: 'Marvel Characters',
     archived: true
   },
   {
     name: 'item 3',
     groupName: 'Marvel Characters',
     archived: false
   }
 ],
 [
   {
     name: 'item 1',
     groupName: 'DC Characters',
     archived: false
   },
   {
     name: 'item 2',
     groupName: 'DC Characters',
     archived: true
   },
   {
     name: 'item 3',
     groupName: 'DC Characters',
     archived: false
   }
 ]
];

const hasArchived = groupItems => groupItems.some(x => x.some(({ archived }) => archived));


console.log(hasArchived(data));
```

Comment: Yeah I don't understand the downvotes because that worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: I downvoted because in my book, a proper answer to this question should do two things: a) primarily: address the logic error made by OP (see my comments below the question) b) point to the docs for `Array.some()` *and* `Array.flat()`. An answer that is basically rephrasing the docs is by definition "not useful".

Comment: I chose to write an answer from scratch because it's way shorter than the original attempt, I'm not rephrasing the docs but simply linking to it, and by the way I didn't use `Array.flat()` at all. Thanks for commenting, though